# Windows 8 slow network wakeup from sleep

Tags: windows-8, network-adapter, wake-on-lan

The problem is that Windows 8 is far more slower than Windows 7 waking up from sleep if you consider network adapter.

With following settings:

[image]

Going to sleep and back looks like this:

[image]

And without "Allow the computer to turn off this device...":

[image]

[image]

It is twice as fast! Only thing is that I need also wake-on-lan.

So my question is: Is there a way to keep my network connection on even in sleep mode so I could also use wake-on-lan?